# Contentholder as reference to web form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, frame

I have got a master page with three content holders. Say; Header, Menu and Content.

I can use Iframes or regular frames, but is there a way to specify the three content holders as follows and redirect them to three different web forms?
The reason I ask this, is because I do not want to specify my menu over and over again for every single web form.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the point of a master page. A master page should contain the markup/code that is common to the content pages or nested master pages that reference it. Put the menu code into the master page.

```
<!-- Menu code here -->
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="Home">Home"</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact">Contact"</a></li>
</ul>
!-- End menu code -->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MenuPlaceHolder" runat="server">
     <!-- On the content page, your page specific menu code would go in the <asp:Content> that references this  -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder >
```

As an alternative to (or in conjunction with) master pages, you can use [user controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). You place your menu code in the user control and embed it in master pages or content pages. But if you always want it in the same place, then a master page makes more sense because of the [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

There is absolutely no reason to use an iframe for this.